# How to parse to <media:thumbnail> using XmlPullParser in Android?

Tags: android, xml, rss, xmlpullparser

i want parse the image url from  tag in my rss feed.
here is my xml feed?

```
<media:content url="http://www.sunsetclub.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/266494881968332-300x199.jpg" width="300" height="199" medium="image" type="image/jpeg"><media:copyright>Sunset</media:copyright></media:content><media:thumbnail url="http://www.sunsetclub.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/266494881968332-80x80.jpg" width="80" height="80"/>
```

i can parse it with DOM parser but i want to parse it with XmlPullParser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
private String readThumbnail(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "media:thumbnail");
    String thumbnailUrl = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url");
    parser.nextTag();
    return thumbnailUrl;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the below exception 

12-15 18:32:32.440: W/System.err(32320): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}media:thumbnail (position:START_TAG <item>@2:1042 in java.io.StringReader@2c9062cc)